# API or datasets for age & gender distributions of the world

Tags: data-request, api, demographics

### Data request

**Data:** I am looking for an API oder dataset where I can find age distribution (age groups: percentage of an age group according to the population) and gender distributions for each country of the world. Something like this:
[Zensus Germany](https://www.destatis.de/DE/ZahlenFakten/GesellschaftStaat/Bevoelkerung/Bevoelkerungsstand/Tabellen_/lrbev01.html)

**Context:** I am working on my Master's Thesis and would like to compare my scientific samples to the population.

**Region:** I need Data from the whole world.

**License:** Unfortunately I am a Student and can't spend more that 50 Euro on this data.

**Format:** A JSON API would be perfect. XML, CSV, XLSX or any other common data type is ok too.

**Authority:** I need the data to be reliable. That means, the sources of the data have to be visible and official.

**Non-answers:** I have tried:

- Open Data Network
- World Bank
- U.S. Census Bureau

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think [geoba.se](http://geoba.se) might interest you, although I'm not sure how reliable their sources are.

Unfortunately, geoba.se doesn't have an API, but you could try to scrape the data yourself using code like the one found on [this answer](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/10649/average-monthly-temperatures-for-cities-around-the-world/10651#10651).

When I have more time, I'll update this answer with a bit of code.

Comment: That site just has the population. But the population is not separated in age groups. As I said, I need it to be like an age distribution. And the statistics of the site are wrong.

Comment: If you access ecah country's page on that website you can see the population distribution between age groups and genders.

Comment: Check the [U.S. page](http://geoba.se/country.php?cc=US&year=2017) on that website for example.

Comment: Now I see what you are talking about. When I searched the site, I did not find that particular page. Perfect thanks a lot. I think I can adjust the wrong population numbers with a ML algorithm.